# How to avoid extension case sensitivity

Tags: php

Guys I have the below code

```
<img border="0" src="<? echo $address?>.jpg" width="100" height="75">
```

It's supposed to return the address of an image in the database and add the .jpg extension to it and show the image on a browser. but the problem is some of the images are .JPG (upper case) therefore the image will not be loaded.

Is there anyway to avoid the case sensitivity of the file extension in PHP?

Comment: Why not just rename the files to `.jpg`?

Comment: This isn't a PHP issue, it's an operating system "issue"... and teaches us that case does matter

Comment: I have alot of files on the database already

Comment: Well if the database doesnt have any of their current extensions, you have nothing to change in the database. You should go rename all the actual files to a unified format, and going forward no longer save files with improper casing.

Comment: If I could only write a code that would read .jpg/.JPG ( both file extensions) my problem would be solved

Comment: File extensions aren't special, they're just the last few characters of the file name. If you've got the same file name with the extensions jpg and JPG, they're as different as any other two files. If the extension is only ever upper or lower case, the easiest thing to do might be to run `file_exists` on both and display the right one. Alternatively, just loop over all the files you have currently, and update the database to also store the extension.

Comment: @iainn I did as you said on the first solution, I have the below code but it has some syntax errors, by any chance you can tell whats the syntax error here?                                <?
                                    if(file_exists($address.".jpg"){        ?>
    <img border="0" src="<? echo $address?>.jpg" width="100" height="75"><br><?}?>
                                <? else{ ?>
                                <img border="0" src="<? echo $address?>.JPG" width="100" height="75">
                                <? } ?>

Comment: @Mustafa see below answer. I edited the code you wrote here in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to mix PHP and HTML by opening and closing PHP.
It just makes the code hard to read and it's easy to make misstakes.

```
if(file_exists($address . ".jpg"){
    echo '<img border="0" src="' . $address . '.jpg" width="100" height="75"><br>';
}else{ 
    echo '<img border="0" src="' . $address . '.JPG" width="100" height="75"><br>';
}
```

Comment: I put yours, this is the error which I got    Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: It's a better solution to fix the files to be lowercase than to run a file exists check every time a page is fetched.  Or to fix the database to include the file extensions.  Fix the design instead of applying more duct tape.

Comment: @DaveS agree but OP seems to want the duct tape. If it's only a few files then renaming them manually might be a solution, if not a code could do it, but if you only display one image per page then I'd use the duct tape too. I would fix the problem but keep the duct tape for the old files.

Comment: @Mustafa you must have some other code that is causing that problem. I'm sure this code will not cause such an error. Doesn't the error show what row the problem was encountered?